# Visual Studio Code - C# extension does not recognize the Unity classes

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to set up my VS Code in order to properly work with a Unity project using Windows 10 as OS. This is what I've done:

- Installation of Unity v.2019.3.0a2;
- Installation of Visual Studio Code v.1.40.2;
- Installation of C# (the Visual Studio Code extension);
- Installation of .Net;
- Setting up VS Code as Unity Script Editor (as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity));

At this point I imported my project root folder in the VS Code workspace but the IntelliSense function doesn't work. So I read [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/dotnet) and then I ran:

```
dotnet new console
dotnet run
```

Now it seems that the IntelliSense works but VS Code doesn't recognize the Unity classes and, for this reason, my project is full of errors. Is there a way to fix it or to import the UnityEngine package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need .Net for working with Unity projects.
Just install Microsoft .Net Framework 4.7.1 SDK to make your C# Omnisharp VS Code extension work properly. Nothing else should be done, just open your project and everything should be OK.

See your VS Code OUTPUT->Omnisharp Log, it'll ask you to install .Net Framework SDK

Also, you need to open your project with Unity Editor at least once, otherwise you'll get a lot of `The name 'gameObject' does not exist in the current context [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS0103)`, `The type or namespace name 'GameObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS0246)` and so on erros in your VS Code even for a workable project.